# Electric flux density and electric field displacement vector are the same quantity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

I was told by my professor that electric flux density and electric displacement vector are the same quantity.

Electric Flux Density is the amount of flux per unit area. This is given by $\frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$.

But Electric Displacement Vector is given by $\vec D= \epsilon_0 \vec E$  which would be equal to $\frac{Q}{4 \pi r^2}$, which is clearly not the same.

So where am I going wrong in understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [electric displacement or the electric flux density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field), is equal to the charge per unit area (let’s talk about conductors) that would be displaced across a medium if it were placed in an electric field. That is, in your example

$$D = \frac{Q}{A}$$

where the area $A = 4 \pi r^2$. Note there is no $\epsilon_0$ in the denominator. This means that

$$D = \epsilon_0 E$$

meaning

$$E = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} D $$

or

$$E = \frac{Q}{A\epsilon_0}= \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2 } $$

which is consistent, and is the electric field produced by charge $Q$ at a distance $r$.